# how make div viewport height, not page height in CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

All the suggestions to use `top: 0em; bottom 0em;` are incorrect. If the page is taller than the viewport, that code stretches the div beyond the viewport's bottom.

The other suggestion to use `100vh` unfortunately doesn't have enough support (I need it to work in the Android browser prior to 4.4).

Is this possible with only CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an element 100% height, set your html, body, and element to have a height of 100%.

```
html,
body,
#your-element { height:100%; }
```

**EDIT - Snippet:**

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
html,body,div { height:100%; }
div { background: #0f0; }
```

```html
<div></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Please re-read my post. I want it to be viewport height, *not* page height.

Comment: @DonRhummy - please try the code, that's what it does.

Comment: My code wasn't working with that because I had another div that was `visibility: hidden` and iOS Safari wasn't pssing the scroll gesture to the non-hidden div (but firefox, chrome both do)

Answer (score 0):

if your container can be fixed, you can just use `height: 100%`

If you want any other positioning, you will need to do this with javascript.